# Using a CSV parser, I am trying to select multiple items from the CSV. It won't let me choose more than two however

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

Like I said, I'm using a CSV parser which can be found here.[The CSV Parser](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823670/Csharp-Light-and-Fast-CSV-Parser)

I am able to successfully run the code using this

```
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileSaveLocation))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var data = CsvParser.ParseHeadAndTail(reader, ',', '"');

            var header2 = data.Item1;
            var lines = data.Item2;

            foreach (var line in lines.Take(5))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < header2.Count; i++)
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line[i]))
                    {
                        sb.Append(header2[i] + "=" + line[i]);
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
            }
        }
```

But I want to be able to select about 10 items. So if I try to add a new variable like:

```
var test = data.Item3;
```

It won't work.

When I do try to run it, it tells me this:

> Error 1   'System.Tuple,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Item3' and no extension method
>   'Item3' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Tuple,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>>'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\repo\Scriptalizer\default.aspx.cs    82  37  Scriptalizer(1)

It will throw an error before I ever try to run the program. It says it cannot resolve Item3. How can I get it to let me put as many columns as I want?

Also, is there a way to dynamically select items? Say the user can input "ignore the first 3 lines" for example, how could I declare these and get the correct columns?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this CSV parsing library in particular, but it sounds like you need the following:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileSaveLocation))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // Get the header and rows as a two-item tuple
        var data = CsvParser.ParseHeadAndTail(reader, ',', '"');

        // Get header and and rows into separate variables
        var header2 = data.Item1;
        var lines = data.Item2;

        // This is where you get the rows you want
        // So in this example, we'll skip the first
        // 3 lines and then get the next 10 lines
        var filteredLines = lines.Skip(3).Take(10);

        // Iterate through the lines and do whatever you need to do
        foreach (var line in filteredLines)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < header2.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line[i]))
                {
                    sb.Append(header2[i] + "=" + line[i]);
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that filteredLines does not skip the columnns, but skips lines.

So essentially the 3,10 is telling it to start at line 3 and get up to 10 instead of the entire document. When  change your for loop's i start location that seems to skip lines.

Comment: Are you trying to skip lines, or skip columns?

Comment: Skip columns, I figured it out though using your example! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing which worked.

```
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileSaveLocation))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var data = CsvParser.ParseHeadAndTail(reader, ',', '"');

            var header2 = data.Item1;
            var lines = data.Item2;


            for (int i = 4; i < header2.Count; i++)
                sb.Append(("\"" + header2[i] + "\"" + ","));

            sb.Append(sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);



            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                for (var i = 4; i < header2.Count; i++)
                {
                        sb.Append("\"" + line[i] + "\"");
                    if (i != header2.Count - 1)
                    {
                        sb.Append(",");
                    }
                }

                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```